# django return querylist instead of one item query

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I am querying in django models with filter but 
Instead of finding list of query I want django to return one query

`product = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug)`

it return `<QuerySet [<Product: Product object (2)>]>`

instead I want something like this

`<Product: Product object (2)>`

so I can access fields of that objects like `product.price`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a filter which will return a queryset.  If you want the one item that matches the criteria, use get.

```
product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will have just one item in your results you can access it directly using [first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#first)

```
product = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
```

Or using [get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
try:
    p = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print("That product doesn't exist.")
```

If you have a list of items in your result, then iterate through them:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug)
for product in products:
     print(product.price)
```